# Where to download the FPGA bitfile of NI cRIO-9068

Tags: fpga, labview

I got an error when I am running the Labview, please see the attached picture.

> [image: Error_Image]

It seems the `bitfile` is not matching with the system version, since I just updated the software, maybe I should download a new bitfile?

Where can I download one?

Comment: One thing I would try first is going to Measurement and Automation Explorer (type "max" in the Windows start menu), then expand your cRIO under Remote Systems on the left (cRIO needs to be on). Select Software, and then click "Add/Remove Software" at the top of the screen. See if there is a newer version of NI-RIO that you can update to on your cRIO, select it if so, and click "Next" a few times. Not sure this will help, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did try, but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the LabVIEW-Software you are trying to use is dynamically loading a bitfile to the FPGA. Whoever compiled the bitfile was using a different version of NI-RIO so you will need to recompile the bitfile from source / ask the original author to send you an updated version, or downgrade your installation of NI-RIO.

Comment: Thank you! And how can I downgrade my NI-RIO?

Comment: You need to uninstall your NI-RIO Installation in windows, install an older version and then reformat your cRIO with the now older installed version.

Comment: Thank you very much Phillipp, can you also please let me know how to recompile the bibfile? I would like to try both ways in case the other doesn't work.

Comment: You need the original Source Code and Project of the Bitfile. Please refer to NI documentation on how to recompile then. Please consider marking the answer correct if it helped you.